# Navigate to settings screen when location is off in Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I want to navigate to Settings screen from my app when the location of the device is off.I did this in android,but i want to do it using CodenameOne. How can i able to achieve this in CodenameOne without using native interfaces.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's something that only exists in Android and is not as commonly used now-days. Location is always on for modern Android devices since even if you turn off the GPS network location still works.